# Getting index from LVALUE reference returned by substr

Tags: perl

Is there a way to get an index from an LVALUE reference in Perl?

e.g. given:

```
$x = "0123456789";
$two = \substr($x, 2, 1);
$four = \substr($x, 4, 1);
```

`$two` and `$four` are now references into `$x`, that is

```
$$two eq '2';
$$four eq '4';
```

and if you change any of them, the content of `$x` will change.

My question is, is is possible to get the index that the reference is pointing to given only the reference?

e.g. `magic($four) == 4` or at least `diff_magic($two, $four) == 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `ref($ref)` gives `LVALUE`, `$ref` is a reference to an SvPVLV.

```
>perl -MDevel::Peek -e"Dump(\substr('abcdefghij', 3, 4))"
SV = IV(0x7eb360) at 0x7eb364
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x7eb284
  SV = PVLV(0x4bf7e4) at 0x7eb284
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (GMG,SMG)
    IV = 0
    NV = 0
    PV = 0
    MAGIC = 0x49f12c
      MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_substr
      MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_substr(x)
    TYPE = x
    TARGOFF = 3
    TARGLEN = 4
    TARG = 0x4a83a4
    FLAGS = 0
    SV = PV(0x7e8b7c) at 0x4a83a4
      REFCNT = 2
      FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,READONLY,pPOK)
      PV = 0x4ad824 "abcdefghij"\0
      CUR = 10
      LEN = 12
```

Yes, it's possible using [B](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B).

```
use B qw( svref_2object );

my $ref = \substr('abcdefghij', 3, 4);

my $sv = svref_2object($ref);
die("Not a PVLV\n") if !$sv->isa('B::PVLV');

my $lv_type = $sv->TYPE();
die("Not a substr lvalue\n") if $lv_type ne 'x';

my $targ_ref = $sv->TARG()->object_2svref();
my $ofs      = $sv->TARGOFF();
my $len      = $sv->TARGLEN();

print("substr('$$targ_ref', $ofs, $len)\n");
```

```
substr('abcdefghij', 3, 4)
```

Not sure why you'd want this.

Comment: Trivia: `pos`, `keys` and `$#a` are the other creators of PVLVs.

Comment: @Borodin might be interested in this answer.

Comment: As for what I need it for: I'm doing some rather complex parsing/replacing that involves some recursiveness and carrying around the indexes is becoming more of a burden for those few cases where I actually need them. When I do need them I just have to find out how much replacing has been done since the references that point after them have to be adjusted.

Comment: In a parser, I would use regex match position associated with the string. It's what's used by `/\G.../g`, but it can be queried and set using the `pos` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't possible directly.

Use of `substr` is rare, especially as an lvalue, but it can be very useful in combination with regular expressions.

What you are asking for seems to be unnecessary. It sounds like a module has been rather too clever with its encapsulation. If you describe better what you are trying to do then I am sure we can help you.